# How to add a new canvas with animation in openlayers3 or openlayers4

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas, openlayers-3

I had drawn an **animation** in **canvas** like [this](https://air.nullschool.net/) and rendered a map using openlayers4. I want to add this canvas to the map[openlayers canvas] in next step.

I had used **ol.source.ImageCanvas** add a boundary to openlayers, so I try to add the canvas with animation using ImageCanvas, but failed.

What's more, openlayers [API](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.source.ImageCanvas.html) said **ol.source.ImageCanvas** method only the **image canvas** can be added. I didn't know whether the **animate canvas** so does.

Should I insit on using **ImageCanvas** method or try others?

Can someone give me an example if I abandon the **ImageCanvas** method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some tries, I got a solution! Haha!

**First**: the **ol.source.ImageCanvas** can **still** use, but you will get a stopped animate just like a screenshot.

**Second**: must know the [ol.map.render()](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.Map.html#render) in openlayers3 or openlayers4, whose description is:

> Request a map rendering (at the next animation frame).

Thus, you can use it to  **refresh the map and get the next animation of canvas**.

The following is snippets of my code:

```
    var topoCanvas = function(extent, resolution, pixelRatio, size, projection) {
    // topo features;
    var features = topojson.feature(tokyo, tokyo.objects.counties);
    var canvasWidth = size[0];
    var canvasHeight = size[1];

    var canvas = d3.select(document.createElement('canvas'));
    canvas.attr('width', canvasWidth).attr('height', canvasHeight);

    var context = canvas.node().getContext('2d');

    var d3Projection = d3.geo.mercator().scale(1).translate([0, 0]);
    var d3Path = d3.geo.path().projection(d3Projection);

    var pixelBounds = d3Path.bounds(features);
    var pixelBoundsWidth = pixelBounds[1][0] - pixelBounds[0][0];
    var pixelBoundsHeight = pixelBounds[1][1] - pixelBounds[0][1];

    var geoBounds = d3.geo.bounds(features);
    var geoBoundsLeftBottom = ol.proj.transform(geoBounds[0], 'EPSG:4326', projection);
    var geoBoundsRightTop = ol.proj.transform(geoBounds[1], 'EPSG:4326', projection);
    var geoBoundsWidth = geoBoundsRightTop[0] - geoBoundsLeftBottom[0];
    if (geoBoundsWidth < 0) {
        geoBoundsWidth += ol.extent.getWidth(projection.getExtent());
    }
    var geoBoundsHeight = geoBoundsRightTop[1] - geoBoundsLeftBottom[1];

    var widthResolution = geoBoundsWidth / pixelBoundsWidth;
    var heightResolution = geoBoundsHeight / pixelBoundsHeight;
    var r = Math.max(widthResolution, heightResolution);
    var scale = r / (resolution / pixelRatio);

    var center = ol.proj.transform(ol.extent.getCenter(extent), projection, 'EPSG:4326');
    d3Projection.scale(scale).center(center).translate([canvasWidth / 2, canvasHeight / 2]);
    d3Path = d3Path.projection(d3Projection).context(context);
    d3Path(features);
    context.stroke();
    // above code is add a topoJson boundary to canvas
    // below code is add an animation to canvas
    var settings = createSettings(tokyo, {
        width: canvasWidth,
        height: canvasHeight
    });
    // reset the projection and bounds for animation canvas
    settings.projection = d3Projection;
    settings.bounds = geoBounds;

    var mesh = buildMeshes(tokyo, settings);

    when(render(settings, mesh, {
        width: canvasWidth,
        height: canvasHeight
    })).then(function(masks) {
        when(interpolateField(stations, data, settings, masks)).then(function(field) {
            // wind moving animation
            animate(settings, field, canvas);
            // refresh  the map to get animation
            window.setInterval(function() {

                map.render();
            }, 50);

        });
    });

    return canvas[0][0];
}
```